# remove MBR of corrupted disk with 0 bytes

Tags: linux, hard-drive, storage, dd, reset

My Problem is that I have a external SSD drive which got corrupted and shows:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 0 sectors, 0 bytes
```

And

```
Problem reading disk in BasicMBRData::ReadMBRData()! 
Warning! Read error 22; strange behavior now likely! 
Warning! Read error 22; strange behavior now likely! Partition table scan:
MBR: MBR only
BSD: not present
APM: not present
GPT: not present
```

Therefore I looked how to remove the existing MBR because it looks like this is the problem. I found following command that overrides the MBR space with zeros

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=446 count=1
```

but because the disk shows only 0 Bytes the command can not be executed and I get following error:

```
dd: error writing '/dev/sdc': No space left on device
```

Does anyone have any other idea how to remove the existing partition tables? because like it is at the moment I cant even format the SSD.

Comment: Exactly one year later, yesterday, have the same problem with an WD Elements disk. Did you solve this issue?

Comment: unfourtunately I could not fix it. But it must have something to do with the adress tables which are all showing to null and I therefore it says the disc has no space.

Answer (score 0):

After something happened with a Ventoy installation, I was unable to use gparted (The device /dev/sdg is so small that it cannot possibly store a file system or partition table.  Perhaps you selected the wrong device?), gdisk (Disk is too small to hold GPT data (0 sectors)! Aborting!).  In my case, I was able to perform `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdg bs=512 count=1` and the drive would load, but reported a size of 512 bytes.  I then performed `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdg bs=512 count=976773168` as this was the size reported by dmesg (`[sdg] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)`).  It failed with:

```
dd: error writing '/dev/sdg': No space left on device
98701929+0 records in
98701928+0 records out
50535387136 bytes (51 GB, 47 GiB) copied, 184.593 s, 274 MB/s
```

After an unsuccessful attempt to use sfdisk to restore the partition table, I removed the drive from the USB dock it was in (RSHTECH) and attached it using a USB->SATA adapter and it worked fine, was able to resinstall Ventoy with no errors.  **In my case, the problem was the USB docking station (which I have not previously had any issues with).**  If you are attaching the disk via a non-standard method, you may wish to try a different way of interfacing.